# How do companies manage to work remotely to meet client deliverable?

Tags: collaboration, team-building

In this situation of COVID-19, many business have affected. still, some companies are performing well while working remotely to meet their client deliverables and deadlines. 
How are they managing to work collaboratively?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about UX as defined in [help/on-topic] but should be asked at Workplace SE ([workplace.se]).

Comment: @maxathousand Thanks for suggesting to me. I will ask the same in the workplace forum.

Comment: @HarshalKotkar I'd suggest you take a look around first and get a feel for how to ask good questions there. I'd probably guess that this question would be a little too broad to fare well over there. If you can focus your question to one particular aspect, it may be more answerable (e.g. scheduling, status updates, or collaborating with coworkers). You may find that your question has already been asked, or that articles on the web about working remotely (of which there are many now) may help you out instead.

Comment: This question needs more specifics. A cleaning company obviously can't meet client deliverables when the staff is staying home; but other companies' work isn't bound by physical presence. Furthermore, I'd suggest asking specific question, e.g. how a certain business practice is being handled when people work remotely, rather than an open ended "how to they do it" without specifying what "it" really entails.

Comment: Didn't we just close this question?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul OP asked it on UX.SE first, was redirected here and reposted it, then the UX question got migrated here so we ended up with both copies.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully working remotely yet collaboratively is something that is import in this environment. Previously it wasn't critical for success.

In the past having all the employees working from home was viewed as a mode of operation that would be difficult to maintain. Companies generally allowed some work to be done from home as a employee perk. If they did allow a portion of the work to be done out of their sight managers and customers worried about productivity of those employees they couldn't see.

Now having the infrastructure in palace, or quickly available, to allow all employees to work from home is a strength. Managers still worry about productivity of people they can't see. That is why some managers and companies want to constantly check in. They want to see everybody on chat. They want to see everybody via video. The good managers and companies have figured out that even if the remote employee is only 2/3rds as productive that is far better than letting all their employees go and closing the company.

Of course some business can't allow the employees to work from home. That makes their business model in this crisis more difficult. Of course the last crisis was different as will be the next one.

Comment: But ... "some managers" are certainly not "all managers!"  Whenever I've been responsible for hiring, I looked for *professionals.*  And found them.  The people I could trust.  The people who took their responsibility to their employing company seriously ... the people who were determined to *earn* their keep, no matter where they were earning it from today.  I made it my business to try to keep them.  **:-)**  (And: *"Frankly, I'm not paid to be your Daddy.  I've got my own job to do, and that doesn't include making sure that you are actually doing yours.  If so, I hired the wrong person.")*